# Simplify an Algebraic Equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

$u$ and $v$ are vectors and $C$ is a symmetric matrix in the sense that $C^T=C$ with the assumption:
$$||v||_2=||u||_2$$
so how we can have: 
\begin{equation}
0<-(u-v)^TC(u-v)
\end{equation}
from:
\begin{equation}
-2u^TCv<-u^TCu-v^TCv
\end{equation}

Comment: Are there any conditions on $C$? If $C^{T} = C$ i.e symmetric, then the result falls out pretty easily.

Comment: Very clearly, this is possible iff $u^TCv=v^TCu$.

Comment: yes  CT=C, can you describe more?@Mattos

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with $-2u^TCv<-u^TCu-v^TCv,$ we have

\begin{align*}
0<&~-u^TCu-v^TCv-2u^TCv\\
=&~-u^TCu-v^TCv-u^TCv-v^TCu&(*)\\
=&~-(u-v)^TC(u-v)
\end{align*}
where the $(*)$ use the fact for any column vectors $x,y$:
$$x^TCy=(x^TCy)^T=y^TCx$$
for $x^TCy$ is just a $1\times 1$ matrix, i.e., a real number.